# Orchard View Changes Not Saving & Modules Not Installing

Tags: asp.net, razor, orchardcms

**Our Setup:**

Orchard v1.5.1
Microsoft Azure hosting
Relevant Modules: Theme Editor 1.4.1, System Editor

**Issues:**

Upon trying to edit the content of a few pages using the System Editor tool we found that none of our changes were showing on the front end. We could leave the theme editing page, come back, and our changes are preserved, but they do not show up on the front end. This is happening for all pages on the site.

We had been using the Theme Editor module to make changes to the theme, but it has been disabled for awhile now. But because we were having issues editing views, we disabled the System Editor and enabled the Theme Editor, hoping it would fix the issue. But now we just see a server error if we try to edit the Theme (going to the Theme area and clicking on the CSS or HTML tabs throws the error). This is the error:

> SERVER ERROR IN '/' APPLICATION.

Now in an attempt to fix this issue we Disabled the Theme Editor module and tried to install a newer version of it (1.4.2), but received this error:

> 'bin\Orchard.Core.dll' already exists. Skipping...
>
> 'bin\Orchard.Framework.dll' already exists. Skipping...
>
> Package installation failed: There was an error installing the
>   requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write
>   access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the
>   site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to
>   these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster
>   control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is
>   recommended to remove write access to these folders.

We are unsure how to proceed as nothing has been changed on the server side this week, and all of our changes to the theme today were minor bits of HTML, so why the system is throwing all of these errors is bizarre. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know System Editor (and I don't see a module by that name on the gallery) but Theme Editor is editing files on disk. That's a big no-no for Azure, unless you are on the new Azure Web Sites (which doesn't seem to be the case from what you're saying). On an Azure instance, you don't install new modules, and you don't modify the file system (your instances may get restarted at any point, and the file system is not getting replicated across servers).
Your options are to move to Azure Web Sites, or to not edit your themes or install modules online, but to deploy new images with the new theme and modules when you want to make changes.